# useHead is updating title on mounted and is not updating on activated hook

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I am using useHead for updating title in pages, titles are updating on mounting of pages  but when I revisit pages, title of page doesn't get updated.

When I revisit the page title of page should be updated again as it get updated on when page is mounted ( rendered first time )

I am using UseHead for updating title as

`useHead({ title: "Join Us", });`

Comment: Would you mind giving us more details why you want to update the page title when it is revisited? What will be the new page title when the page is revisited?

Comment: thank @ReaganM but I have found the solution, there was an issue in the previoous version of nuxt ( 3.0 ) which I was using, and this has been fixed in new verison of nuxt 3.2.